Algorand with PyTeal Free testnet with free test amount
I'm new to blockchain development. Trying to implement basic HTLC protocol for Algorand with Pyteal. I used blockdeamon, but as I understand it have only mainnet, where I need real Algos to make transactions.
So, which testnet I can use, where I can create a free test account with test algos, and just check transactions and other functionalities?
